# Confusion about order of operations

Tags: arithmetic

The question is simple, why the following is wrong!?

24 $\div$ $\frac{9}{-3}$ = 24 $\div$ 9 $\div$ -3

Comment: It is heavily implied with the way you wrote it that you have $24\div (\frac{9}{-3})$.  Note that Division is not associative.  Unlike addition and multiplication, generally you have $(a\div b)\div c \neq a \div (b\div c)$.  As such, writing $24\div 9\div (-3)$ is ambiguous whether you mean $(24\div 9)\div (-3)$ or if you mean $24\div (9\div (-3))$.  As it so happens, the first is wrong but the second is correct.

Comment: i agree totally but I didn't but parentheses to  $\frac{9}{-3}$ in my question

Comment: Even so, by writing it in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ it is implied that $\frac{a}{b}$ is to be treated as a number (in this case a rational number), so you have the number $24$ divided by the number $\frac{9}{-3}$.  It is slightly ambiguous, but if people had to choose a way to interpret it, that would be the way it would be interpreted.

Comment: the $\div$ symbol is a horrible piece of notation that should be avoided precisely for this reason.  It is ambiguous in how it should be interpreted.

Comment: If $a-b-c$ is not ambiguous, then why should $a \div b \div c$ be?  Isn't it logical to work from left to right?  If $a-b-c=(a-b)-c$, the for the sake of consistency, $a\div b\div c=(a\div b)\div c$.

Comment: @Batominovski The only reason $a-b-c$ is unambiguous is that people have agreed to the convention that it means $(a-b)-c$ and not $a-(b-c)$. (Nowadays, we "agree" to this convention only in the sense that it is drummed into us in school and we get bad grades if we disagree.) People have not, as far as I know, agreed to such a convention for division.

Comment: If a teacher gave you this "exercise", he/she should be heavily apprehended.

Answer (score 1):

$24\div\frac{9}{-3}=\frac{24}{\frac{9}{-3}}=24\times\frac{-3}{9}=24\times(-3)\div9$

Answer (score 1):

Division, unlike addition or multiplication, is not [associative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Associative.html).

So the result of:
$$
a \div b \div c
$$

will depend on the order you perform the operations in. Thus in most cases

$$
a \div (b \div c) \ne (a \div b) \div c
$$
In your case, I think you have implied:

$$
24 \div (9 \div -3) = (24 \div 9) \div -3
$$

which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

$a \div \frac{b}{c} = a * \frac{c}{b}$

So $24 \div \frac{9}{-3} = 24 * \frac{-3}{9}$

Answer (score 0):

Fractions are thought of as being a single object.  Here is something a little bit more complicated

$\frac {x^2 - 3x + 2}{x - 1}$

We evaluate everything above the line together and everything below the line together.  No parenthesis are written but they are implied.

So,we see the $\frac 9{-3}$ and reduce the fraction before moving along.

$\div$ happens left to right.

Most math beyond middle school gets rid of the $\div$ notation precisely because it is frequently ambiguous.